# Hide sidebar if empty - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, hide, sidebar

I want to hide my sidebars if there is no content in them, unfortunately there are 26.000 functions to call your sidebar, which I'm not really interested in. All I want is to hide my sidebars if they are empty, and show them when they contain a widget.

Now I'm not sure if I should use the get_sidebar function or the dynamic_sidebar function. Also I'm wondering if I should use the sidebar-name.php to call it or the ID in the functions.php

Answer (score 1):

I just applied this on my WordPress site and it works.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) { ?>
    <ul id="sidebar">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

In my case I had this on my functions.php

```
function videobgFour() {
register_sidebar( array(
'name' => 'Background Four',
'id'   => 'videobg4',
));
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'videobgFour');
```

And this on my header.php file

```
<div class="box">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('videobg4'); ?>
</div>
```

So I had to use the PHP code in this way.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'videobg4' ) ) { ?>
    <div class="box">
       <?php dynamic_sidebar('videobg4'); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

In this case the HTML Markup will print only when widget is active.

Comment: Its not working for the block-based widgets

Answer (score 0):

O think this does the trick:

```
<?php is_active_sidebar( $index ); ?>
```

However, in my very little experience with WordPress, it is either you have a sidebar or you do not. Depends on the template you are have selected weather it has a sidebar or not... and I think it works better that way

Comment: Well I got this

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'subjects-sidebar' ) ) { ?>
     <?php get_sidebar('subjects-sidebar'); ?>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: No, I'm pulling my hair out on this one. At the moment I'm trying to substitute get_sidebar for dynamic_sidebar